# How to make an S4 class inherit correctly from another S4 class?

Tags: r, inheritance, r-s4

I am creating two S4 classes, where class Employee inherits from the other class Person.

The definition for both the classes is as follows:

```
setClass("Person", slots = list(name="character", age="numeric"))

setClass("Employee", slots = list(boss="Person"))
```

I am creating once instance each of these two classes,

```
alice <- new("Person", name="Alice", age = 40)
```

This works well, but when I try to create an instance of Employee using :

```
john <- new("Employee", name = "John", age = 20, boss= alice)
```

It gives the error as below :

```
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  invalid names for slots of class “Employee”: name, age
```

Can I not create the object in this fashion ?

Comment: You forgot to specify the base class for `Employee`; use `setClass("Employee", slots = list(boss="Person"), contains = "Person")` and this should work.

Comment: @ Updated the question, still the same error

Comment: @Sarang `contains` is a parameter of `setClass` and must be outside of the list. Study the parentheses in nrussell's comment carefully.

Comment: @nrussell I want to give you the credit, so if you post your solution as an answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: @Sarang I've adapted your question and title so it can be found more easily when people look for this information. That said, your question is easily solved by reading the documentation of `?setClass`, so it is likely it will be closed.

Comment: @Joris Meys Thank you, but I wasn't planning on writing up an answer so you should just leave yours posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per nrussel's comment:

the argument `contains` of the function `setClass` deals with inheritance. You want the class `Employee` to inherit from the class `Person` (i.e. an employee is a special type of person). So

```
setClass("Person", slots = list(name="character", age="numeric"))
setClass("Employee", slots = list(boss="Person"), contains = "Person")
```

will do the trick.

```
> alice <- new("Person", name="Alice", age = 40)
> john <- new("Employee", name = "John", age = 20, boss= alice)
> john
An object of class "Employee"
Slot "boss":
An object of class "Person"
Slot "name":
[1] "Alice"

Slot "age":
[1] 40


Slot "name":
[1] "John"

Slot "age":
[1] 20
```